# I'm playing a Marilith demon who is leader of a evil campaign. After hitting very high levels, how should I go about keeping the party together?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dungeons-and-dragons, roleplaying, adnd-2e, evil-campaign

During a while of playing a 2e session with multiple 3.5e conversions, I have recently (In the past 7 years) experimenting with playing Evil campaigns and playing Monster characters such as Mind Flayers (Which I'm really good with), A Gloom (Part of an Epic Level beginning game), Baatezu, Trolls, Fairies, Sprites, Hunefers (Another Epic Level beginning Campaign), Bugbears, and a small hand full of other monsters.
In this campaign, we have been going on for 2 years of gameplay, reaching levels between 64-76

### Current Party

- Nuetral Evil **Medusa** (Lvl 72 Wizard/ Archmage 5)
- Chaotic Evil **Marilith Tanar'ri** (Lvl 77 Warrior)
- Chaotic Evil **Vrock Tanar'ri** (Lvl 38 Barbarian/Lvl 34 Legendary Dreadnought)
- Chaotic Evil **Succubus Tanar'ri** (Lvl 66 Bard/ Lvl 2 Rogue)
- Lawful Evil **Noble Efreeti** (Lvl 20 Fighter/Lvl 48 Fire Elementalist)
- Neutral Evil **Chameleon Greater Barghest** (Lvl 56 Assassin/Lvl 20 Perfect Wight)
- Chaotic Evil **Vampire Drow** (Lvl 32 Blackguard/ Lvl 20 Cleric/ Lvl 24 Divine Emissary)
- Neutral Evil **Corpse Tearer Linnorm** (Lvl 60 Necromancer/ Lvl 18 Dread Necromancer)

I am having a slight problem trying to figure out how to keep this diverse group together. The blood war, the personal problems, and the ambitions in the group are causing us to be a bit nervous. Each of us is having a difficult time with personal goals. During our time we have battled the armies of heavens, slaughtered many baatezu/devils, plundered villages, battled against the forces of good, fought against the harpers including battles against Mystra's chosen, and basically ravaged most planes. Now after a while of our power growing, some of us have become slightly more distant from others and others have become a little suspicious of each other, causing many to create secondary plans and safeguards just in case. I do not want this to grow out of control, for this campaign is too amazing to quit. I need a solution that does not involve a common enemy (for specific reasons) or involves money. So, how should I string together this merry band?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. It sounds like this question's asking for help generating plot ideas, and the site doesn't handle idea generation questions, instead recommending such a call for ideas be posed on a forum like one of those found [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/8610). Also, I suspect very few experts will be qualified even to offer suggestions as to how to do *anything* in a campaign that involves 8 level 70 PCs; that kind of power level is—to this humble *3.5* expert—actually unimaginable. Still, thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you can't discuss this out of character? D&D parties travel together for story reasons, but also for out of game reasons. Even evil campaigns require buy-in from the players and that buy-in should be continuous to ensure harmonious play even when you're torching orphanages that attacked you first.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical +1 This is a great point; shame it can't be an answer.

Comment: I didn't even realize there were rules for having level 70+ PCs... I thought epic levels of 20-30 were already the kind of thing barely anybody ever reached and was mostly just for theorycrafting. What even do you fight at those levels to be a challenge?

Comment: Plot based situations, Abominations, powerful NPCs,  Mystery, intrigue, politics, other universes.

Comment: @Theik [This](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/3481/Immortals-Handbook--EPIC-BESTIARY-Volume-One?src=also_purchased) product includes "[o]ver 40 truly epic monsters ranging from CR 10 to over CR 1000; including the unstoppable Neutronium Golem and the awesome World Flayers." Research will show, however, that it was not well received.

Answer (score -3):

A group of Chaotic Evil characters is always going to be tough to wrangle.  I think you have to be able to offer (especially the CE characters) something that helps each character personally.  And probably have something strong enough in your back pocket to force compliance, which in your case is only going to be the most powerful of the Gods, such as Nerul.

Comment: Thank Glob it's not a whole campaign of Chaotic Neutral characters! They tend to have the worst "my guy syndome" moments. :)

Comment: Ah, would you imagine a Chaotic Neutral party full of wild mage Kinders?